# unable to position element at the same place across different os browsers

Tags: html, css

I am trying to vertical center 2 spans in a div on top of each other. I am able to vertical center them using relative positioning but the issue is the same CSS code positions the element in mac os browsers differently.

here is how it looks on windows - any browser, same result which is perfect
http://prntscr.com/mj2knr both counter 5 and text is positioned perfectly.

here is how it looks on any browser on mac os http://prntscr.com/mj2llu 
I spent a good amount of time in rectifying the issue but it works at one place at a time only.

Below is my HTML structure

```
<div class="avatar_image sl">
    <span class="nsl">5</span>
    <br>
    <span class="slt"> shares left </span>
</div>
```

The corresponding CSS is

```
.sl{
    background-color: #ff9466;
    color: #fff;
    height: 80px !important;
    width: 80px !important;
    border-radius: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 10px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: -35px;
    right: -35px;
    font-family: fontMedium;
}
.nsl{
    font-size: 50px;
    position: relative;
    top: 20%;
}
.slt{
    font-size: 8px;
}
```

Comment: You might want to use flexbox instead of two spans - that might provide more consistent results across browsers.

Comment: How about using flex-box

Comment: look for a "reset-css" that clears all the different default stylings of each browser... also use margins with relative positioning not top,right etc.

Comment: I looked at this for well over an hour and consider myself expert in `CSS`. It's not easy to create a cross-browser, pixel-perfect representation of this. And I blame `CSS` for it.

Comment: For cross-browser comparability, it can be useful to use a normalise.css file, to create consistent base styles to overwrite.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it on Safari but try it out, it should be more consistent across browsers. Reset of padding and margin on body/html is optional, also you may want to adapt container dimensions according to your needs.

```css
body, html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.sl{
  background-color: #ff9466;
  color: #fff;
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  font-size: 10px;
  z-index: 1;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: fontMedium;
}

.nsl{
  font-size: 50px;
  position: relative;
  top: 5%;
}

.slt{
  font-size: 8px;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 8%;
}
```

```html
  <div class="container">
    <div class="avatar_image sl">
      <span class="nsl">5</span>
      <br>
      <span class="slt"> shares left </span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: The number 5 is far away from the text beneath it (Mac/Firefox 65).

Comment: That's exactly what I mean.

Comment: I am not sure whether it is possible to bring them closer using flexbox, so I used position to achieve to desired result.